# Can you add a variable to a file path?

Tags: php, path

I was wondering if you can add a variable to a file-path.

Example:

```
path: C:\\users\\john\\school\\hardware.properties";
```

I want to make a variable of the word preceding the . (dot) - in this case, "hardware" - so the user can write a name in a form and search/get another property.

Comment: You mean like `C:\users\john\school\hardware.$property`?

Comment: the other way around

Comment: sorry my english is not very good

Comment: So like C:\users\john\school\$name.properties?

Comment: Be aware that inviting user-supplied data into a path may be a vulnerability because they can add relative path changes (like `../`) and go where you don't want them to.   You must sanitize user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make it a string and add the var into it

```php
$name = $_POST['name']

$path = "C:/.../".$name.".properties"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just make more sure what Jasper B want to write:

In your form you have some submit input and text input.

You will get datas from inputs so you will just access them like:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

After you just put `$name` variable to path like:

```
$path = "C:\users\john\school\".$name.".properties";
```